# Не могу изменить пагинацию в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Использую Wonderflux с дочерней темой. Стоял плагин pg-navi, я его удалил. 
На страницах с пагинацией выводится "Page 1 of 2 >", хочу изменить оформление, но не могу найти как реализован вывод.

Если добавить функцию the_posts_pagination(), появляется дубликат "1 2 Далее" после каждого поста, хотя размещаю, за закрытыми div.

Искал поиском, в папке шаблона the_posts_pagination нигде не дублируется.

На хостинге кеш сайта отключен, плагинов кеширования нет и не было.

Единственное грешу на плагины пагинации, которые я удалил.

Может быть пагинация может быть реализована другими функциями, о которых я не знаю?

Страница с пагинацией:

```
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Read %s', 'wfx-girder' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_excerpt('');?>
    </div></div>
<?php   the_posts_pagination( $args );


$args = array(
    'show_all'     => false, // показаны все страницы участвующие в пагинации
    'end_size'     => 1,     // количество страниц на концах
    'mid_size'     => 1,     // количество страниц вокруг текущей
    'prev_next'    => true,  // выводить ли боковые ссылки "предыдущая/следующая страница".
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'add_args'     => false, // Массив аргументов (переменных запроса), которые нужно добавить к ссылкам.
    'add_fragment' => '',     // Текст который добавиться ко всем ссылкам.
    'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' ),
);
    ?>
```

Файл [functions.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ql916lardvgznjl/functions.php?dl=0)

Вернул pg-navi, - визуально без изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте сами шаблоны, single.php, category.php и так далее, там должна стоять функция вывода пагинации, закоментируйте ее(что бы не удалять), найдите в гугле какой то код для пагинации и протестите его, сделайте все как в обучении. например вот ссылка http://dimox.name/wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/